# pygettext: Seen unexpected token "%"

Tags: python, internationalization, gettext

I am currently trying to implement internationalization in an application (Python 2.6) and have run into an error involving string formatting.
A string marked translatable looks like this:

`foo = _("I would like to have %d pounds of cheese" % amount)`

Running `pygettext` on my source tree then complains when it hits this line:

```
$ pygettext .
*** ./foobar.py:45: Seen unexpected token "%"
```

The resulting `messages.pot` file does not contain the string after pygettext has done its work.
What is the way to go for string formatting with gettext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translate the unreplaced string. Or replace on the translated string.

```
foo = _("I would like to have %d pounds of cheese") % amount
```

Comment: Yes. The error is caused by the fact that what`s inside the `_(...)` needs to be a string literal, not an expression.